# Setting back form.pristine on press "Cancel" Button on [Angular 2] form

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am implementing **Cancel** button on **Angular 2** on click on 
`onCancel($event)` should return to Pristine all the fields (Also I implemented a Cloned **model** that is assigned to current **model** so I can get all data back).

ATM when press'cancel', the data returns to original one, but `ng-dirty` still on the fields

Comment: I come up with a simple solution, just showing or hiding button is changes exists on the form, it works and does the job.. but still the fields are not pristine.